How do I properly set the parameters for a scikit-fuzzy trimf function
When I try to manually set the parameters of using the trimf function it throws an error when I try to input 0. Here is the minimum code that reproduces the problem
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl

universe = np.linspace(0,1,100)
test_input = ctrl.Antecedent(universe,'test_input')

test_output = ctrl.Consequent(np.linspace(0,1,100), 'test_output')

test_input['poor'] = fuzz.trimf(universe, [0 , 0.2, 1])
test_output.automf(3)

rule1 = ctrl.Rule(test_input['poor'], test_output['poor'])

test_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1])
test_sim = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(test_ctrl)

test_sim.input['test_input'] = 0
test_sim.compute()

print(test_sim.output['test_output'])

I know If I change the trimf parameters to [0, 0, 1], it will run without throwing an error, but I want to know why this happens

because when using the Skfuzzy library's trimf function, using [0, 0.2, 1] throws an error that doesn't meet the trigonometric membership function parameter.
Changed to [0, 0, 1] to be able to operate, which can meet its special valid situation.
